# SupportMapFragment hides DrawerLayout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, supportmapfragment

In API 10 (2.3.3, 2.3.6) DrawerLayout opens under map. But when I press on map, it works like I press on DrawerLayout list item.
In versions 16+ all work excellent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just invalidate ListView in NavigationDrawer on opened:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_drawerLayout);

    mDrawerToggle = new  ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.from,  R.string.april) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            leftMenuList.invalidateViews();
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

    };


    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```